# Migration from Hibernate to eclipse link as the JPA provider

Tags: eclipselink

We are planning to migrate from Hibernate 4.0 to eclipse link as our JPA provider can someone let me know what kind of effort would be involved has anyone gone down that path.

I am keen because of the multi-tenancy is superior in eclipse link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Late answer, but I believe the question may be relevant for others and answer can be more complicated than it seems.

I consider only 100% standard JPA usage. There are some differences that may be crucial. E.g.:

- Hibernate, by default, does not cache. EclipseLink, by default, caches massively. You have to check documentation of boths how to migrate your caching.
- Hibernate can find (scan) classes even in Java SE environment by default, EclipseLink doesn't do this. Both do it in EE environment as specified.
- There are bugs in both providers, even with 100% JPA you may hit some regularly depending on the complexity of your mapping, whether and how you use JPQL, etc. Examples from our practice:

  - Hibernate does not produce correct SQL for deletes across joins like: `delete from Dog d where d.breed.name = 'collie'` ([link](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-9711))
  - Or rather exotic EclipseLink's delete of entity with `@OneToMany` referencing non-`@Id` property ([link](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=332309))
  - As another example, although now fixed, there were also problems with Java 8 streams on lazy lists in EclipseLink because they misused `Vector` (extended one without maintaining superclass' protected fields' invariants).

Considering how many bugs are open in both projects (which is by itself probably expected) you may get into bug cross-fire when you try to migrate back and forth.

So to wrap it up:

- Mind JPA provider specifics where the JPA specification is not, well, specific (there are many unspecified behaviors left to providers). Implicit caching settings are one example. You need to read JPA provider docs to use the proper properties for the provider, etc.
- Mind the bugs. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Short answer.  It depends.

Long answer.  It might be trivial if you use 100% standard JPA, or you could have to rewrite everything if you use the Hibernate API directly.

Best answer.  It's going to be non-trivial, but not an outrageous time commitment if you are using JPA.